# Listing all notes in node js get request?

Tags: node.js

I have been following [this tutorial](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/building-a-simple-node-js-api-in-under-30-minutes-a07ea9e390d2). The only real question I have after completing the tutorial is how do I list all of my notes in an api endpoint? I've tried the code below, but it throws `ReferenceError: result is not defined`. I'm a newb to Node.js, so any references would be great.

```
app.get('/api/notes', (req, res) =>
{
    db.collection('notes').find({}).toArray(function(err, res)
    {
        if (err)
        {
            res.send({ 'error' : 'An error has occurred.' });
        }
        else
        {
            res.send(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The callback that you pass to `toArray(...)` has a parameter `res`, which you probably meant to name `result`, hence why `result` is not defined.

Comment: Thank you so much!